# Trying to associate a function to a specific radio generated on Django to show a modal

Tags: javascript, python, django

Im trying to make a modal show up on a onclick event function on django, but whenever i try to do it, instead of overwriting/adding the function on the radio, they just generate another radio on the side, how i can do that, at the same time, not generating another radio?

This is the html on django where the radios it is generated

```
<div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-12 mb-1" style="line-height: 0px;">
            <h6 style="margin: 0px;">TONALIDADE</h6><br>
          </div>
          {% for choice, valor in situacoes_disponIns|slice:":3" %}
            <!-- descobrir como colocar parametro dentro da função -->
          <input type="radio"    class="col-lg-2 col-12 mb-1 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" value="{{ choice }}" name="sTonalidade" id="id_situacaoIns">
          {% if choice is 2 %}
          <input type="radio" onclick="funcao1();" class="col-lg-2 col-12 mb-1 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" value="{{ choice }}" name="sTonalidade" id="id_situacaoIns">
          
          {% endif %}
```

And this is the function where i call the modal to show up on clickevent

```
<script>
          function funcao1() //
          {                
               $("#cq-open").appendTo("body").modal("show");  
          }
          </script>
```

[This is happening right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxbfp.png)

[And this is what i want to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW90m.png), keeping the function I assigned(onclick that call the modal)

Comment: I am confused to your **english** writing, if you *re-check* and *edit* your **english** then it will be easy for me to understand your problem and I hope I can help you.

Comment: Sry about the grammar, i've edited and added some scrnshots to clarify my question!

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/